# Complicated SQL Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 where each week we load our loyal customer's data. We load each customer's ID, how much they purchased and the quantity.
We still load the loyal customer's data each week even if they don't buy anything that week. I need to find out which week a customer becomes inactive. 
The rule for making a customer inactive is as follows: the customer failed to purchase a product at least 3 weeks in a row AND they failed to purchase more weeks in a row than the number of weeks they purchased a product or failed to purchase 10 weeks in a row.

For example, let's say the customer purchased a product the first week but they failed to purchase a product the next two weeks and in that scenario the customer is still Active since they did not fail to purchase a product at least 3 weeks in  a row. If they purchased a product in week 4 and 5 (purchases in week 1 and missed in week 2 and 3)  then in order for them to become inactive they would have to miss 6 weeks in a row because we would consider them to be active in week 2 and 3 even though they did not purchase a  product in those weeks. Now let's they failed to purchase a product in week 6 and 7 but purchases a product in week 8, so in that case they would have to miss purchasing a 
product 9 weeks in a row. Let's say they purchases a product in week 9, 10, 11 so in that case they only have to miss purchasing a product 10 weeks in a row instead of 12 weeks because if they did not purchase anything 10 weeks in a row then they are automatically inactive. I'm not sure if that's possible to find out which week they became Inactive in SQL. I was thinking about writing a SQL function for that but I'm stuck on that. I thought I could use the LAG fuction but not sure how to proceed. Is this even 
possible in SQL?

```
WITH CTE_A AS 
(
   SELECT
       *,
       LAG(CASE
              WHEN grossamount > 0 OR qty > 0 THEN 1 
              ELSE -1
           END) OVER (ORDER BY (PurchaseDate)) AS ActiveYN
   FROM 
       parity
),
CTE_B AS 
(
    SELECT
        *,
        LAG(activeyn) OVER (ORDER BY PurchaseDate) + ActiveYN AS ActiveYN1
    FROM 
        CTE_A
)
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    cte_b
```

Comment: Which SQL server, client, and language?  I am pretty sure it can be done with a user-defined aggregator in Apache Derby, if that happens to be what you are using :) .

Comment: Your definition is inconsistent.  The first paragraph says  "they failed to purchase more weeks in a row than the number of weeks they purchased a product ".  But the example says that a week without a purchase is considered active and hence to be used for the calculation.

Comment: So if the customer buys a product 4 weeks in a row and misses week 5 and 6 but buys a product in week 7 then we would consider them to be active for week 1 to 7 including week week 5 and 6. But if the customer buys a product for 4 weeks in a row but misses the next 5 then we would consider them to be in inactive in week 5.If they buy a product in 4 weeks in a row but misses the next 5 weeks in a row and then purchases a product in week 10 then we would consider them to be inactive in week 5 and in week 10 they would be considered as new customer.